# SocketException on cancel call using OkHttp

Tags: java, android, okhttp

The following code represents downloading a file. The call will be canceled when the Observable is disposed. In my case the Observable will be disposed in the Fragment's onDestroy() method (due to the fact it will not need to continue downloading the file on a Fragment that is or will be destroyed). Whenever a scenario takes place of cancelation during the downloading process of the file, this code will crash with a SocketException. The message can either be a "Socket Closed" or a "Socket operation on non-socket". My question is how to properly cancel an ongoing download request using OkHttp?

The code:

```
Request request = //..
final Call call = client.newCall(request);

   call.enqueue(new Callback() {

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call call, IOException error)
       {
          Log.e("Acme", "OnFailure:", error);
          emitter.onError(error);
       }

       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException
       {
           if (response.isSuccessful())
           {
               BufferedSink sink = null;
               BufferedSource source = null;
               try
               {
                   Log.d("Acme", "onResponse: Start writing..");
                   sink = Okio.buffer(Okio.sink(file));
                   source = response.body().source();
                   sink.writeAll(source); // Crash on this line.
                   sink.flush();

                   emitter.onNext(file);
                   emitter.onComplete();
               }
               catch (IOException exception)
               {
                   Log.e("Acme", "onResponse: Exception writing file:", exception);
                   emitter.onError(exception);
               }
               finally
               {
                   Log.d("Acme", "onResponse: Trying to close..");
                   Util.closeQuietly(sink);
                   Util.closeQuietly(source);
                   Log.d("Acme", "onResponse: Closed..");
               }
           }
       }
   });

   emitter.setCancellable(new Cancellable() {

       @Override
       public void cancel() throws Exception 
       {
           if (!call.isCanceled()) 
           {
               call.cancel();
           }
       }
   });
}
```

Console:

```
D/Acme: onResponse: Start writing..
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp https://acme.nl/...
Process: nl.acme.app.development.debug, PID: 12432
java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on non-socket
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:151)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:120)
    at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:138)
    at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:236)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:45)
    at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec$FixedLengthSource.read(Http1Codec.java:385)
    at okio.RealBufferedSource.read(RealBufferedSource.java:45)
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.writeAll(RealBufferedSink.java:97)
    at nl.app.acme.infrastructure.network.Api$44$1.onResponse(Api.java:3322)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:135)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: The code shown doesn't have anything to do with rx-java or rx-android.

Comment: Can you attach the code of Util.closeQuietly() method?

Comment: That’s working as designed. When you cancel a call its streams throw exceptions.

Comment: @JesseWilson I know it works as intended, but it is throwing a fatal exception whilst it is surrounded by a try/catch clause. Do you have any suggestions on how to this correctly?

Comment: @ThomasNeuteboom, theproblem might resides within the  Util.closeQuietly(sink);
                   Util.closeQuietly(source);
methods, you might doing operations on closed stream that cause to the exception in the finally clause, please attach the code of this methods, additionally, your exception happens on the 3322 (??) line of your API.java, what is this line exactly?

Comment: @yosriz Hi Yosriz, the line that crashes (3322) is sink.writeAll(). The Util closeQuitely method is from the OkHttp library. It simply closes a Closeable (interface that contains close() method), ignoring any checked exceptions. Does nothing if the Closeable is null. The problem persists using the 'normal' route of closing the sink/source.

Comment: Hi, this may be old but I ran into the same issue and maybe this will help someone. I surrounded sink.writeAll() with a try/catch(e: SocketException) as opposed to the OP who is catching an IOException and it seems to have resolved the issue on my end.

Answer (score 1):

In code

```
catch (IOException exception)
{
    Log.e("Acme", "onResponse: Exception writing file:", exception);
    emitter.onError(exception);
}
```

you are sending `onError()` to emitter who is already unsubscribed while you fragment destroyed.
Please do check:

```
if (!emitter.isDisposed()) emitter.onError(exception);
```